# Textarea and radio buttons visibility issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm trying to do is basically check if the response from the server contains alternatives. If it does then it should print the alternatives out , hide the text area where I would answer the question if the question did not contain alternatives and show the radio buttons. Problem is, it prints out the response, but never hides/shows the text area or the radio buttons.

I tried putting the code for the visibility in a button to see if it works on click, and it does, but it does not work when I put the same code in the if statement.

Also, another problem is that instead of printing out the actual alternatives, it just prints out Object object, but when I try to print out the question, it prints it out correctly.

`HideAllRadios` and `ShowArea` functions are basically the same as what's in the `if` statement, but reversed.

Here is the code:

```
 QuestionReq.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if(QuestionReq.readyState === 4 && QuestionReq.status === 200) {


    response = JSON.parse(QuestionReq.responseText);
    console.log(response);
    questionLink.innerText = response.question;
    url = response.nextURL;

    // questAltLink.innerText = response.alternatives;

     if(response.alternatives !=null){
       questAltLink.innerText = response.alternatives;
       AnswerArea.style.visibility = "hidden";
       RadioArea.style.visibility = "visible";
      }

    HideAllRadios();
    ShowArea();
  }
```

Here is how they are declared:

```
var questions = function () {

  var AnswerArea = document.getElementById("AnswerArea");
  var RadioArea = document.getElementById("radioplace");
```

Comment: Can we see some of the markup? ... and maybe some more script as it is unclear how variables like `AnswerArea` is declared

Comment: Sure: var AnswerArea = document.getElementById("AnswerArea");
  var RadioArea = document.getElementById("radioplace"); also

Comment: Prolly some problem with your JSON may be you are double-wrapping it.Can you show a sample json response?

Comment: @Novice Object {id: 21, question: "What is 2 + 8?", alternatives: Object, nextURL: "http://vhost3.lnu.se:20080/answer/21", message: "You got your question! Now send me which alternati…nswer via HTTP POST to the nextURL in JSON-format"},in the console right next to this output is a little arrow, if i click on it it sorts all the stuff in like a dropdown menu thing (question, alternatives etc) and then a little arrow next to alternatives, if i click on that arrow too then i will get a drop down menu with the actual alternatives

Comment: Well , i asked for JSON not parsed object .Anyway , just check whether that `if` ever gets to run by using some `alert()` when alternatives are present.Also check the semicolon in `vhost3.lnu.se:20080/answer/21";` that doesn't look right may be it's throwing some error